# Transfer in Ataturk airport

Tags: airports, international-travel, airport-transfer, connecting-flights

I am a Pakistani national going to Turkey and Egypt. I have a Qatar airways flight. When I reach Ataturk Airport I change flights to Turkish Airlines for Cairo. Can I get my Turkish Airlines boarding pass in the transit area? If I pass immigration my visa will be used. So I want to change flights airside. Could anybody tell me is there are Turkish Airlines counters like in Bangkok, where every airline has a small counter for transfers.

Comment: https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/any-questions/transfer-transit-passengers/

Comment: What about your luggage? Do you have any checked luggage?

Comment: No checked luggage hands carry only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last year I flew from Birmingham International (UK) to Istanbul Atatürk Airport (TK) for my final destination, which was Suvarnabhumi Airport (TH). When checking in in the UK, I was given a boarding pass for my flight from Birmingham to Turkey. Once I arrived in Turkey I went through the transfer funnel, through security (I think immigration I cannot really remember) then into the transit terminal.

Once there, I went straight over to the Turkish Airlines desk, handed them my passport and they printed a boarding pass right there for me. This sounds relevant in your case, don't worry after all you are in Turkey. They can and will be able to issue you a boarding pass in the transit lounge (after security).

Comment: Your memory is a little off.  The transfer desk is BEFORE security.  You get off the plane (heading "down" if you're given the choice - you can only go "up" if you already have a boarding pass), then walk to the transfer desk which is near the transfer security (depending on which direction you're coming from).  Only once you have a boarding pass will you be allowed pass through security which leads you directly (well, via an escalator) to the departure area.

Comment: I remember quite specifically, waiting outside a Turkish Airlines desk, where an African gentlemen pushed in front of me and was told to get to the back of the queue. I then had a boarding pass printed and went straight to the terrace to smoke a cigarette. Between getting my boarding pass printed and going for a smoke I never passed through security thus I must have already passed through it. I actually fly out using the same route later this week, I will send you a picture of the desk I used personally.